# Set content view in Activity with merge tag as root?

Tags: android, merge, android-framelayout

I have an `Activity` and a simple layout.

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.my.layout
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </com.my.layout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I would like to replace `FrameLayout` by merge tag, but in a result I get following error during `setContentView`:

```
01-25 17:08:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(25837): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app/my.app.MyActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
```

Comment: I think the problem is only with this `com.my.layout` layout. May I know how you have declare that?

Comment: No it's not. You can reproduce it using LinearLayout as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, try removing HoloEverywhere. It causes problems with merge tag.

Answer (score 1):

Curious, this behavior does not seem to be universally true.  I can run a simple example in the emulator or on one of my Nexus devices and the application has no problem inflating a main layout with the `<merge>` tag as the root of the hierarchy.  Can you reproduce this on multiple devices?

Technically, just from a glance at the AOSP, this behavior is not possible with the Android `Window` and `Activity` implementation unless a particular OEM has modified its behavior (Motorola is notorious for doing this).  In the AOSP source:

1. The exception can only come about when `LayoutInflater.inflate()` is called with a `null` parent view parameter.
2. `Activity` just passes `setContentView()` off to its parent `Window`
3. `Window` calls `LayoutInflater.inflate()` with the content view as the parent, and if it were null at this stage a nasty `RuntimeException` would have been thrown by the framework code.

As a side note, this may not be something you want to do anyway.  I understand the reason for wanting to replace a seemingly useless parent in your hierarchy, but one thing that guarantees is that your application always knows what its parent is so it can properly expect `LayoutParams` to be evaluated.  When using `<merge>`, the root content view of your hierarchy could be a `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, or other depending on the version of Android on the device, and this may cause confusing behavior if you expect root `LayoutParams` to behave in a specific way.

Comment: HoloEverywhere was the case, anyway thanks for comprehensive answer :)